# Why does this script stops after creating 66-ish PDF?

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook, pdf-generation

I wrote a script that creates a PDF version of an email, this version below makes sure that an email doesn't have an attachment (version with attachment behaves in exactly the same way, by the way). It runs smoothly and without any problems until it reaches the 65-ish email, and then it stops with this error:

> Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'

Any idea why this might be happening?

Here is my code:

```
Sub PrintEmails()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItem As Object, myItems As Object, objDoc As Object, objInspector As Object
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileNumber As Long

FileNumber = 2

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("NewEmails")
Set myItems = olFolder.Items

FolderPath = "F:\MyFolder\VBA\Emails\"


For Each myItem In myItems

If myItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then

    FileName = myItem.Subject
    IllegalCharacters = Array("/", "\", ":", "?", "<", ">", "|", "&", "%", "*", "{", "}", "[", "]", "!")
        For Each Character In IllegalCharacters
            FileName = Replace(FileName, Character, " ")
        Next Character


    Do While FileOrDirExists(FolderPath & FileName & "(" & CStr(FileNumber) & ")" & ".pdf")
        FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
    Loop

    If FileOrDirExists(FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf") Then
        Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
        Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FolderPath & FileName & "(" & CStr(FileNumber) & ")" & ".pdf", 17
        Set objInspector = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing
        FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
    Else
        Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
        Set objDoc = objInspector.WordEditor
        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf", 17
        Set objInspector = Nothing
        Set objDoc = Nothing
    End If

Else

End If

Next myItem


End Sub

Function FileOrDirExists(PathName As String) As Boolean

Dim iTemp As Integer

 'Ignore errors to allow for error evaluation
On Error Resume Next
iTemp = GetAttr(PathName)

 'Check if error exists and set response appropriately
Select Case Err.Number
Case Is = 0
    FileOrDirExists = True
Case Else
    FileOrDirExists = False
End Select

 'Resume error checking
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does your inbox contain *only* mail items, or are there any other types of item?  If you only want to process mails then add a check for the type of `myItem`.  Which line throws the error?

Comment: Yes, that inbox contains only mail items, and the line that throws an error is the: `Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector` right after the `If FileOrDirExists(FolderPath & FileName & ".pdf") Then`

Comment: Do you still see the same problem if you don't touch the Inspector and Word editor in the loop?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko I'm pretty new to VBA, so I'm not sure how I could avoid doing that....

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I just commented out the whole section with the Inspector and Word, and the script 'looped' through the whole folder without any problems.

Comment: Does it always fail on the same message?  If you remove all the other messages does it still fail on the same item?  Maybe there's some specific problem with that message?

Comment: @TimWilliams It doesn't. I tested it with different messages and folders, no matter what, it just stops around 65-ish message.

Comment: Can you try a format directly supported by MailItem.SaveAs, such as olMHTML or olDoc? This way you can use MailItem.SaveAs without using Inspector and Word.Document.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko But the thing is, the final format has to be PDF.

Comment: I suggested that as  test. But what you can also do is create a **single** instance of Word.Application to import and then export all the files generated by MailItem.SaveAs

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I was able to export all those emails as Word documents without any problems. But now I'm not really sure how to import and then export all those files as PDF. Can you please tell me how to start on that?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcyt0y1f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unable to find a reason why the script would stop working around 65-ish email, but thanks to a few suggestions from @DmitryStreblechenko I came up with this "workaround" solution:

```
Sub PrintEmails()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myItem As Object, myItems As Object
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileNumber As Long
Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents

FileNumber = 2

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("NewEmails")
Set myItems = olFolder.Items

FolderPath = "F:\MyFolder\VBA\Emails\"

For Each myItem In myItems

If myItem.Attachments.Count = 0 Then
    FileName = myItem.SenderName

    IllegalCharacters = Array("/", "\", ":", "?", "<", ">", "|", "&", "%", "*", "{", "}", "[", "]", "!")
        For Each Character In IllegalCharacters
            FileName = Replace(FileName, Character, " ")
        Next Character

    Do While FileOrDirExists(FolderPath & FileName & "(" & CStr(FileNumber) & ")" & ".doc")
        FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
    Loop

    If FileOrDirExists(FolderPath & FileName & ".doc") Then
        myItem.SaveAs FolderPath & FileName & "(" & CStr(FileNumber) & ")" & ".doc", olDoc
        FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
    Else
        myItem.SaveAs FolderPath & FileName & ".doc", olDoc
    End If
    FileNumber = 2
Else
End If

FileNumber = 2

Next myItem

wFile = Dir(FolderPath & "*.doc")

Do While wFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(FolderPath & wFile)
    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FolderPath & Replace(wFile, ".doc", ".pdf"), ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
    objDoc.Close (True)
    wFile = Dir
Loop
objWord.Quit

End Sub

Function FileOrDirExists(PathName As String) As Boolean

    Dim iTemp As Integer

     'Ignore errors to allow for error evaluation
    On Error Resume Next
    iTemp = GetAttr(PathName)

     'Check if error exists and set response appropriately
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 0
        FileOrDirExists = True
    Case Else
        FileOrDirExists = False
    End Select

     'Resume error checking
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Thank you!